# How to mock laravel helper function request

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

How do you mock the request() helper function?

For example if I have a function that makes a call

```
$name = request()->input('name')
```

How do mock that call, I have tried the following but I get an error that it was never called

```
$requestMock = $this->mock(Request::class);
$requestMock->shouldReceive('input')->once()->andReturn($name);
```

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358264/laravel-phpunit-mock-request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel PHPUnit mock Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358264/laravel-phpunit-mock-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `request()` helper (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/05da44d6823c2923597519ac10151f5827a24f80/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L602) it’s retrieving an instance of the Request class from the Container. After you set up your mock Request class and add your expectations you need to bind it to the Container:

```php
$this->app->instance('request', $mock);
```