# Why doesn't Laravel in-memory testing work when seeding is enabled?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, in-memory-database, database-testing

I recently upgraded an application to Laravel 9, and have in-memory testing set up for the unit and feature tests.

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="inmemory"/>
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>

'connections' => [

    'inmemory' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => ':memory:',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    ...
```

Inside of each test, I'm using the following to seed the database, as recommended by the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#running-seeders):

```
protected $seeder = ExampleSeederClass::class;
```

When I run the tests with `php artisan test --parallel` (with or without the `--parallel` switch) all tests requiring a seeder fail with:

> Failed asserting that null matches expected ...

When I simply replace the in-memory database with an on-disk SQlite in my `.testing.env file`, the tests pass as expected (after some initial time to seed the database):

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=testing.sqlite
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Is this a Laravel bug, and if not, what could be happening here?

Here is an example of one of my failing tests:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider idList
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function test_id_verification_method($request, $output)
{
    $user = new User;
    $request = Request::create('/', 'GET');
    $request->merge(['id' => $this->dataName()]);
    $request->setLaravelSession(session());
    $this->assertEquals($output, $user->verify_id($request, $user));
}
```

Comment: I think what I am going to share will not fix your issue, so: the example test is not right at all, just use `$this->get('URL')`, etc, do not create a request yourself and try to execute it. Either way, one super quick extra thing you can do to debug is just run a normal factory and store it and assert if it exists (of course use the `in-memory`): `User::factory()->creat();` and then simply do `$this->assertDatabaseHasCount(User::class, 1);`

Comment: Do the tests run when you don't run them in parallel?

Comment: @cweiske No, as mentioned the problem exists both with and without `--parallel`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I need to manually create the request because my `verify_id()` method expects it, as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65058925/1191147). I've been meaning to convert the tests to use the more modern syntax but I'm not sure it's possible with my method.

Comment: @HashimAziz did you do as I recommended you just for testing? creating a factory and seeing if it works?

Comment: There is a warning about migration squashing for in-memory databases: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#squashing-migrations. That's not related to your problem, but maybe a hint that in-memory SQLite has problems. Maybe use an empty path as database file, since the php-sqlite3 docs say a temporary random db is used in that case: "If filename is an empty string, then a private, temporary on-disk database will be created." - https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.construct.php