# How to mock properly Illuminate\Http\Request class from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, mocking, mockery

I'm trying to test a method from a class which contains a method using the request() helper from Laravel. This is the method:

**Category class**

```
public function getCanonicalUrl()
{
    return preg_match('/\/sale\/./', request()->getRequestUri())
         ? ''
         : url($this->getUrlKey());
}
```

The test should make this helper to catch properly the URI when doing *getRequestUri()* but it's actually returning an empty string. This is one of the thousand tries that I gave to the test.

**Test**

```
public function testCanonical()
{
    // ...

    $requestMock = Mockery::mock(Request::class)
      ->shouldReceive('getRequestUri')
      ->andReturn('/sale/random-string');

    $this->app->instance(Request::class, $requestMock);

    // ...
}
```

Any ideas of how this could be achieved? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You should not mock the `Request` facade. Instead, pass the input you desire into the HTTP helper methods such as get and post when running your test.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking#mocking-facades

Comment: so `$this->get($path)` was the proper and easy way to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/61903688/135114,
if

1. your function under test takes a `$request` argument, and
2. you don't need to do funky stuff to the Request—real route paths are good enough for you

... then you don't need to "mock" a Request (as in, mockery),
you can just **create a `Request`** and pass it, e.g.

```php
public function test_myFunc_condition_expectedResult() {
    ...
    $mockRequest = Request::create('/path/that/I_want', 'GET'); 
    $this->assertTrue($myClass->myFuncThat($mockRequest));
}
```