# How to Mock the Request Class in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to test a function that depends on

```
$request->all();
```

in a method. How do I mock the Request class so `$request->all();` returns

```
['includes' => ['some_val','another_val']
```

in tests?

Comment: [Don't](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mocking#mocking-facades) (see the message at the bottom).

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you to use [`mockery/mockery`](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/getting_started/installation.html). You will have to do this:

In your test method do:

```
app()->bind(
    \Illuminate\Http\Request::class,
    function () {
        $mock = \Mockery::mock(\Illuminate\Http\Request::class)->makePartial();
        $mock->shouldReceive('all')
            ->andReturn(['includes' => ['some_val', 'another_val']]);

        return $mock;
    }
);
```

What you are doing there is:

- Binding the `mock` to the `Request`, so when you do `yourMethod(Request $request)` it will instantiate your mock instead of the real class
- Doing `\Mockery::mock(CLASS)->makePartial();` will first create a mock of that class, and then (`makePartial()`) will allow you to use other non-mocked methods (use real methods) so any method you didn't mock will run real code
- `shouldReceive` will allow the mocked class to mock that method (argument of `shouldReceive`), so we are mocking `all` method and returning your desired value, in this case, the array you posted
- And finally we must return the mock as the instance

---

As @devk stated, Laravel does not recommend mocking `Request` class, so don't do it, but if you need to mock any other object, you can use the code above and it will perfectly work.

Answer (score 2):

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/61903688/135114,
if

1. your function under test takes a `$request` argument,
2. you don't need to do funky stuff to the Request—real paths are good enough for you

... then you don't need to "mock" a Request (as in, mockery),
you can just **create a `Request`** and pass it, e.g.

```php
public function test_myFunc_condition_expectedResult() {
    ...
    $mockRequest = Request::create('/path/that/I_want', 'GET'); 
    $this->assertTrue($myClass->myFuncThat($mockRequest));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by devk, don't mock the request. But Laravel allows you to build an actual request and then call your controller in your test like this:

```
public function testPostRequest() {
    $response = $this->post(
        '/my-custom-route',
        ['includes' => ['some_val','another_val']]
    );
}
```

Comment: That is a posible solution, because maybe he wants to just Unit test, you are doing a Feature test.

Answer (score 0):

This works well, for a mock or you can do as above with the partial depending on  if you want the request object to pass around or inspect

```php
/** @var \Illuminate\Http\Request|\Mockery\MockInterface */
        $request = $this->mock(Request::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('all')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn([
                    'includes' => [
                        'some_val', 'another_val',
                    ],
                ]);
        });
```